# Enviar email através de servidor SMTP ou local(SendMail, Postfix)?

Tags: email, ses

Estou utilizando em meu projeto o Amazon SES para enviar emails transacionais. Até então configurava o framework para conectar diretamente via SMTP utilizando minhas credenciais do Amazon SES, porém vi que não é uma boa pratica pois para cada requisição que solicito, o servidor PHP fica aguardando uma conexão com o servidor SMTP ao invés de enfileirar os emails e retornar a requisição HTTP o mais rápido possível.

Para isso, eu deveria usar um servidor MTA local como o SendMail ou Postfix e configura-lo para enviar através da Amazon SES?

Quando utilizar conexão SMTP direta e quando utilizar um MTA local para essa finalidade?

Comment: embora seja fora de escopo do site amigo segue link para te ajudar https://www.howtoforge.com/howto_sendmail_smtp_auth_tls